# "cannot find -lmpi*" when compiling openmpi code

Tags: compiling, ld, mpi

I had try to install openmpi 1.8.1 from the source code at Ubuntu 14.04 server. I would like to use mpi for large scale calculation on single machine with multi cores.

The simple "Hello world" test can be run without any problem.

However, when I trying to compile the program which I need to use. I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempi 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_mpifh 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mcp2_mpi] Error 1
```

I had try to set the LD_LIBRAY_PATH to the directory where the openmpi lib can be find.
It seems doesn't work. I had try to check the ld command in verbose mode.

```
$ ld -lmpi_usempi --verbose
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libmpi_usempi.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libmpi_usempi.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libmpi_usempi.a failed
ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempi
```

It seems the ld doesn't look for the libraries in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
I had try to create a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ to include the path of openmpi lib. Then the command *sudo ldconfig -v*. I find the following output:

```
    /usr/local/openmpi/lib:
    libopen-rte.so.7 -> libopen-rte.so.7.0.3
    libmpi_mpifh.so.2 -> libmpi_mpifh.so.2.3.0
    libopen-trace-format.so.1 -> libopen-trace-format.so.1.0.0
    libmpi_cxx.so.1 -> libmpi_cxx.so.1.1.3
    liboshmem.so.1 -> liboshmem.so.1.0.0
    libvt-mpi.so.0 -> libvt-mpi.so.0.0.0
    libvt-hyb.so.0 -> libvt-hyb.so.0.0.0
    libvt-mt.so.0 -> libvt-mt.so.0.0.0
    libotfaux.so.0 -> libotfaux.so.0.0.0
    libvt-mpi-unify.so.0 -> libvt-mpi-unify.so.0.0.0
    libopen-pal.so.6 -> libopen-pal.so.6.1.1
    libmpi_usempi.so.1 -> libmpi_usempi.so.1.3.0
    libmpi.so.1 -> libmpi.so.1.5.0
    libvt.so.0 -> libvt.so.0.0.0
    libmca_common_sm.so.4 -> libmca_common_sm.so.4.0.3
    libompitrace.so.0 -> libompitrace.so.0.0.0
```

It seems the Libs are included in the ld search path.

However, I still got the same problem like before.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_usempi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi_mpifh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mcp2_mpi] Error 1
```

Is there some suggestions to this issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The steps you've tried affect the *run time* library search path. Assuming that you are using `gcc`, to set the *compile time* search path you need to use the compiler's `-L` flag

```
   -Ldir
       Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.
```

So for example if you have installed the libraries into /usr/local/openmpi/lib, modify your `gcc` command line to

```
-L /usr/local/openmpi/lib -lmpi_usempi -lmpi_mpifh -lmpi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I had try the way you have mentioned. The error information is the same. I am sure I had the library files in the path. What I am surprise is that LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ld.so.conf.d doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: "cannot find -lmpi*" when compiling openmpi code

Solutions: I try to check the other options in my compiling command line. I add an extra -static in the compile command line. By removing this, it finally works for me.

Comment: You can keep the -static link flag if you have installed the static version of the mpi.

Answer (score 1):

**Working Ubuntu 20.04 setup**

In general, you have to pass `pkg-config` flags to the compilation command to be able to compile, e.g. either:

```
sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags mpi) main.c $(pkg-config --libs mpi)

sudo apt install libmpich-dev
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags mpich) main.c $(pkg-config --libs mpich)
```

depending if you want openmpi or MPICH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427399/mpich-vs-openmpi

In theory both of those compile a simple test like this fine:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 however only the MPICH works because the `libopenmpi-dev` package has a bug and forgot to symlink:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40
```

so you can just do it manually as a workaround:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40 \
           /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so
```

Bug report at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmpi/+bug/1869612

I found this by looking for `libmpi.so` with:

```
locate libmpi.so
dpkg -L libopenmpi-dev
```

But it works if I just pass that directly to the compilation command:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags mpi) main.c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40
```

I also now learnt about the existence of `/usr/bin/mpicc` package from the `openmpi-bin` package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739909/what-is-mpic-file-used-for but the `libopenmpi-dev` version appears broken on Ubuntu also due to the missing `libmpi.so` symlink.

Answer (score 0):

According to
[OpenMPI documentation](https://docs.open-mpi.org/en/v5.0.x/building-apps/building-static-apps.html),
it is suggested not to build MPI statically.
The answer by Wilf confused me because one of my library (CUDD, if anyone is curious)
usually required the `-static` flag to build.
If I just simply remove the flag, the build will fail.

By studying the documentation of [MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www1/mpicxx.html) and [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), I found that `mpicxx -static` and `gcc -static` are not the same idea.
Luckily, CUDD can actually be built as a shared library. I configured and built the shared library, and then the -static flag can be removed without a problem.